# Why didn't I return String from another func?

Tags: swift, xcode, web-services

```
func Login_Webservice(UID:String ,UPD:String )->String
{ 


    var Msg_return :String = ""
    let Login_Auth_url = URL(string:"https://www.example.com/toknconvert/WebService.asmx/Login_Check?ID=\(UID)&PW=\(UPD)")
    let Login_Auth_task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: Login_Auth_url!)
    {(data,resonse,error) in
        let Login_data_Msg = (NSString(data:(data)!,encoding:String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue))
        if(Login_data_Msg?.contains("Success"))!
        {
            Msg_return = "accept"
        }
        else{
            Msg_return = "reject"
        }
    }

    Login_Auth_task.resume()
    return Msg_return
}
```

I create a new function for Web-service(if I don't I have twice same code),but it will get empty,
 
so I try to add `DispatchQueue`.
 It's show 
`"Unexpected non-void return value in void function"`.

Comment: You can't do it like this. you should learn about sync and async task.

Comment: `URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: Login_Auth_url!)` is async task it will not executed on serial queue.  when execution finishes it will return `{(data,resonse,error) in` so you need to use closures